# GIt Config Alias With Quotes and Pipes via Command Line

Tags: git, git-config

I want to create a `sh` script that configures all my git aliases.  Some of the aliases have pipes (`|`) and doublequotes (`"`).  The output I want to see in my `~/.gitconfig` file is:

```
[alias]
    assume = update-index --assume-unchanged
    unassume = update-index --no-assume-unchanged
    assumed = "!git ls-files -v | grep ^h | cut -c 3-"
```

However, running the following three commands yields an incorrect `assumed` entry:

```
# setup git aliases per: http://blog.apiaxle.com/post/handy-git-tips-to-stop-you-getting-fired/
git config --global alias.assume "update-index --assume-unchanged"
git config --global alias.unassume "update-index --no-assume-unchanged"
git config --global alias.assumed '"!git ls-files -v | grep ^h | cut -c 3-"'
```

The third alias (`assumed`) has undesired backslashes:

```
assumed = \"!git ls-files -v | grep ^h | cut -c 3-\"
```

What is the correct syntax to configure the alias **via command line**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need double quotes in .gitconfig.

So the command is:

```
git config --global alias.assumed '!git ls-files -v | grep ^h | cut -c 3-'
```

Comment: and in the `~/.gitconfig` file itself, it will look like `[alias] assumed = !git ls-files -v | grep ^h | cut -c 3-`

Comment: I believe you may need the double quotes in some cases...
For instance if you use the function trick `"!_() {...}; _"` to create aliases with argument handling

Comment: The key thing to make it work was to use single quotes to enclose the command, so `git config` escapes the command correctly in `.gitconfig`.

Comment: At least in Windows 10, you require the double quotes to add other execution commands.  For example `cmd = a.exe \"a\"` is fine without quotes, but to add a `sleep 5` effect, for a total command of `cmd = a.exe \"a\" && sleep 5` it must be enclosed in double quotes.  So in the `.gitconfig` it needs to be `cmd = "a.exe \"a\" && sleep 5"`